# Powershell - Exclude folders in Get-ChildItem

Tags: powershell

How to exclude folders ? Now I hardcode the folder names but i want  it to be more flexible.

```
foreach($file in Get-ChildItem $fileDirectory -Exclude folderA,folderb)
```

Comment: Do you mean to exclude *all* folders?  Or just ones you choose?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

"How to exclude folders ?" , if you mean all folders :

```
get-childitem "$fileDirectory\\*" -file
```

but it works only for the first level of $fileDirectory  .
This works recursevly :

```
Get-ChildItem "$fileDirectory\\*"  -Recurse | ForEach-Object { if (!($_.PSIsContainer)) { $_}}
```

or

```
 Get-ChildItem "$fileDirectory\\*"  -Recurse | where { !$_.PSisContainer }
```

Comment: I understand the question to mean get a list of file paths but not the paths of the folder only (.e.g., dont list /folder1/subfolder but list /folder1/subfolder/log.txt)  This seems to work better for me:  `Get-ChildItem -Recurse . -file | Resolve-Path`

OR for relative paths :  `Get-ChildItem -Recurse . -file | Resolve-Path -Relative`

Answer (score 6):

You can do this by using the pipeline and a `Where-Object` filter.

First of all, the idiomatic way to iterate over a group of files in PowerShell is to pipe `Get-Childitem` to `Foreach-Object`.  So rewriting your command gets:

```
Get-ChildItem $fileDirectory | foreach {
   $file = $_
   ...
}
```

The advantage of using the pipeline is that now you can insert other cmdlets in between.  Specifically, we use `Where-Object` to filter the list of files.  The filter will pass on a file only if it isn't contained in a given array.

```
$excludelist = 'folderA', 'folderB'
Get-Childitem $fileDirectory | 
  where { $excludeList -notcontains $_ } |
  foreach {
    $file = $_
    ...
  }
```

If you're going to use this a lot, you can even write a custom *filter* function to modify the list of files in an arbitrary way before passing to `foreach`.

```
filter except($except, $unless = @()) {
  if ($except -notcontains $_ -or $unless -contains $_ ){
    $_ 
  }
}

$excludelist = 'folderA', 'folderB'
$alwaysInclude = 'folderC', 'folderD'
Get-ChildItem $fileDirectory |
  except $excludeList -unless $alwaysInclude | 
  foreach {
    ...
  }
```

Comment: if I'm not wrong, this still need to specify the folders name to be excluded. Example If I have 100 folders that I need to specify each of them 100 times.  Now  I want to skip this manually process

Comment: You'll need to build a list of the folders to exclude one way or another, whether by doing it manually or by running a different `Get-ChildItem` command.  It depends on how you choose folders to exclude.

Answer (score 4):

@dvjz said that -file works only in the first level of a folder, but not recursively. But it seems to work for me.

```
get-childitem "$fileDirectory\\*" -file -recurse
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to exclude your folders recursively:

```
foreach($file in Get-ChildItem $fileDirectory -Exclude {Get-ChildItem folderA},{Get-ChildItem folderB})
```

Where:

- `$fileDirectory` - search folder
- `folderA`, `folderB` - excluded folders

Answer (score 1):

For future googlers, I have found that files have a property called `PSIsContainer` which is `$true` when they are a directory.
A command listing all files in `$fileDirectory` would be:

```
foreach ($file in Get-ChildItem $fileDirectory | Where-Object -Property PSIsContainer -eq $false)
{
    Write-Host $file.Name
}
```

Note that `-Property` is optional for the cmdlet `Where-Object`.