# Do not copy the folder .git and its content using Copy-Item with PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have a .yaml file where I am using a powershell to copy an item and I do not want to copy the .git folder. Here is my script. It copies the .git folder.

```
deploy_job:
  stage: deploy
  script:
  - Copy-Item . c:\ColdFusion11\cfusion\wwwroot\website1 -Exclude .git* -recurse
```

edit:
I'm able to do it with this. How do I add multiple folders?

```
Get-ChildItem C:\ColdFusion11\cfusion\wwwroot\website1 | where { !(($_ -is [System.IO.DirectoryInfo]) -and ($_.Name -eq ".git")) } | Copy-Item -Destination C:\website1 -Recurse
```

Comment: Exclude doesn't seem to work with Copy-Item. There's a solution to combine Get-ChildItem and Copy-Item to get the desired result: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/731752/exclude-list-in-powershell-copy-item-does-not-appear-to-be-working

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Powershell - Exclude folders in Get-ChildItem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35789888/powershell-exclude-folders-in-get-childitem)